# Click event working fine in mozzila but not in chrome

Tags: jquery

I have one hidden file field and one browse button. When i click on browse button it will fire a click event which clicks on file field. My code is working fine in mozzila but not in chrome. Code is as follows :

```
 $("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").bind({
    click: function(){
      $('#product_master_csv_file').trigger('click');
      return false;
     }
 });
```

I have tried the following also :-

```
 $("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").bind(
    "click", function(){
      $('#product_master_csv_file').click();
      return false;         
 });
```

and

```
$("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").click(function(){
      $('#product_master_csv_file').trigger('click');
      return false;
     }
 });
```

and

```
$("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").live("click", function(){
      $('#product_master_csv_file').trigger('click');
      return false;
     }
 });
```

But this is working fine

```
$("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").click(function(){
      alert("clicked");
     }
 });
```

Comment: No Success.. can please anybody give me the hint so i can go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **bind** , use **ON** method

```
   $("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").on("click", function(event){
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, I've never seen click: written like that, try this:

```
$("#upload, #browse_product_detail_file").bind('click', function(){
    $('#product_master_csv_file').click();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/) looks remarkable. Maybe instead of obsolete `bind`, you should also think of using 'click' jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Its very old way try this way.

As of jQuery 1.4 we can bind multiple event handlers simultaneously by passing a map of event type/handler pairs:

**OLD**

```
$('#foo').bind({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```

**NEW**

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

Comment: The main problem with click event fires a click event i think.

Comment: I dont know what is the problem. but when i write alert in the click event it fires.

Comment: check on console i think that will help to.